# Datos consulta SQL en excel distribuido en celdas

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

actualmente tengo una macro en excel que hace una consulta SQL server y escribe los datos en las celdas.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQnet_Locations.DESCR FROM (((SQnet_TestValues INNER JOIN SQnet_TestDefinitions ON SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_DT = SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK) INNER JOIN SQnet_Users ON SQnet_TestValues.USR_CODE = SQnet_Users.REC_CODE) INNER JOIN SQnet_Locations ON SQnet_TestDefinitions.PARENT_CODE = SQnet_Locations.REC_CODE) INNER JOIN SQnet_Measures ON SQnet_TestValues.MEASURE_ID = SQnet_Measures.REC_CODE WHERE convert(date,SQnet_TestDefinitions.LAST_CHECK) <= convert(date,getdate()-2) AND SQnet_TestValues.TESTDEVICE IN ('4','5') AND SQnet_Locations.DESCR like '%VW216%'
```

Y con el siguiente código escribe todo de la celda B28 para abajo:

```
    'Performs the actual query
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    'Dumps all the results from the StrQuery into cell B28 of the first sheet in the active workbook
    Sheets(1).Range("B28").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub
```

Me gustaría que escribiera los datos de la B28 a la B38 y si contiene más datos que saltase de la C28 a la C38 y asi sucesivamente.

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código actual ya vuelca un Recordset con esa estructura. Quizás se podría modificar el SQL, pero veo mucho más fácil volcarlo y manipularlo en Excel, cortando y pegando.

Por ello, tu código original que se quede como está, y luego podrías ejecutar un proceso así:

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long


'obtenemos el número de fila de la última celda NO vacía en columna B
LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If LR <= 38 Then Exit Sub 'si no hay datos después de fila 38, salimos

i = 39 'empezamos en fila 39
j = 3 'columna C es la tercera

Do Until i > LR
    'lo que queremos copiar siempre está en B y son once celdas. De filas 28 a 38, de 39 a 49, de 50 a 60 etc.
    ' pero en cada copia desplazamos una columna, empezando en C, así que incrementamos j en 1
    ' Siempre queremos pegar de filas 28 a 38
    
    Range("B" & i & ":B" & i + 10).Cut Range(Cells(28, j), Cells(38, j))
    
    i = i + 11
    j = j + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Esto irá desplazando los datos de 11 en 11 y los irá copiando en sucesivas columnas empezando en la C.

Ejemplo en vídeo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! :)